# phpSpec no beCalled([array:0]) matcher found for null

Tags: laravel-5, phpspec

I'm trying to get into the workfow of using phpSpec to desing my classes. I have stumbled on  testing a handle method on one of my event handlers.

My spec:

```
use App\Order;
use App\Models\Payments\Payment;
use App\Services\Payments\PaymentService;
use App\Events\Payments\AccountPayment;

class RecordPaymentTransactionSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function let(PaymentService $paymentService)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($paymentService);
    }

    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType('App\Handlers\Events\Payments\RecordPaymentTransaction');
    }

    function it_should_record_payment_transaction(AccountPayment $event)
    {
        $this->paymentService->recordPayment($event)->shouldBeCalled();
    }
}
```

And this my implementation:

```
class RecordPaymentTransaction {

    public $paymentService;

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * RecordPaymentTransaction constructor.
     * @param PaymentService $paymentService
     */
    public function __construct(PaymentService $paymentService)
    {
        $this->paymentService = $paymentService;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  AccountPayment  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(AccountPayment $event)
    {
        $this->paymentService->recordPayment($event);
    }

}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
 - it should record payment transaction
      no beCalled([array:0]) matcher found for null.
```

Cannot see what I'm doing wrong here, help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function it_should_record_payment_transaction(AccountPayment $event)
{
    $this->paymentService->recordPayment($event)->shouldBeCalled();
}
```

should be

```
function it_should_record_payment_transaction(
    PaymentService $paymentService, 
    AccountPayment $event
) {
    $paymentService->recordPayment($event)->shouldBeCalled();
    $this->handle($event);
}
```

or

```
function it_should_record_payment_transaction(AccountPayment $event) 
{
    $prophet = new Prophet();
    $paymentService = $prophet->prophesize(PaymentService::class);

    $paymentService->recordPayment($event)->shouldBeCalled();
    $this->handle($event);

    $prophet->checkPredictions();
}
```

This is because, when you spec a class, you should only call a public method of it and make expectations on collaborators.

You don't need to (and you are not supposed to do) call collaborators with

```
$this->collaboratorName->method->shouldBeCalled()
```

Use "implicit" mocks (by passing them into spec method signature: if they are used in `let` function and have same name and type, they *are* the same mock for phpspec) or "explicit" mocks that you can obtain by calling `prophesize` on `Prophet` object. The only difference between them is that "implicit" mocks are checked automatically whereas "explicit" ones need to be checked manually (`$prophet->checkPredictions();`)

Comment: This worked, thank you very much for the clarification.